# Respectively - usage

Tags: word-usage

The company chalked a 52.8% and 47.3% growth in revenue and pre-tax profit respectively.

Is the above usage of "respectively" correct? I mean to say:

> The company chalked a 52.8% growth in revenue and 47.3% growth in pre-tax profit

Comment: Was it 52.8% revenue and 47.3% pre-tax profit?

Comment: Yes. I intend to mean that.

Comment: As an aside, the typical usage is not just *chalked* but *[chalked up](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/chalk-something-up)*.

Comment: I think you should normally put a comma before respectively

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct - when we say respectively, it is a way of linking items in one list to the items in another, with the same positions.

> Alice and Bob received sentences of one year and eight months respectively

Alice received a sentence of one year, and Bob received a sentence of eight months.